# unable to load external templates in cordova with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-8.1, cordova-win10

Cordova version 4.0 deploying to Windows 8.1 prevents external templates

```
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'login',
            templateUrl: 'http://ip-address/templates/login.html',
            resolve: resolver('login')
        })
```

Notes: 
This is not a InAppBrowser application.
index.html is local and so is the router.js 
config.xml has

```
<access origin="*" />
```

So any Cross Domain issue should not arise.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, so I'm just commenting. I have this in my index.html file, whereas I needed to access templates on templates.com (as an example): <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.azure-mobile.net http://localhost:1337 http://templates.com">.

Comment: Is there a space there before templates.com ? Can you put the code portion within apostrophe so that it can get formatted and becomes readable. You can use ctrl+k

Comment: ctrl+k only works on questions and answers (not comments). I'll add an answer so that the format will be helpful.

Comment: No worries. I was able to read it. Will try in the morning.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what errors do you get?  What was the indication that the template url wasn't accessible?

Comment: I have solved this problem - posting the workaround shortly. But it is still a cross origin issue `APPHOST9601` and solved it by pre-fetching as text and compiling and adding in `$templateCache` .

Comment: Good deal. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underlying problem seems Cross Origin Issue but solved this with following workaround. The basic theory is that $http.get is able to resolve text/html or application/json.

In `app.run(....)`

```
            var allTemplates = [
                'my-template-1.html',
                'login-template.html',
                'logout-template.html',
                'unsupportedversion.html'
            ];

            allTemplates.forEach(function(template){
                $http.get('http://example.com/templates/'+template).success(function (t) {
                    $templateCache.put('templates/'+template, t);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $rootScope.appErrors.push(template+' failedToLoad');
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, so I'm just commenting (see comments under question). I have this in my index.html file, whereas I needed to access templates on templates.com (as an example):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.azure-mobile.net http://localhost:1337 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com">
```

Comment: Did not work. Also whitelisted my url in `config.xml`.